Is the vibration from my fridge enough to harm my aquarium?
I keep a small snail aquarium on top of my dormitory fridge. Recently, someone suggested that this setup is unethical because the fridge's vibrations might disturb the water and stress the snails. However, the aquarium is placed on a thick rug for cushioning.
The tank is equipped with a large air pump and sponge filter, as well as a decent-sized internal filter. Both of these create significantly more water movement than the minimal vibrations from the fridge.
How exactly could my fridge harm my aquatic life? Does this concern only apply to louder or older refrigerators?

Edit:
I have been asked to show previous research. This is a bit difficult to do, as my previous research failed to answer my question (hence why I am here).
But perhaps these will help:

https://www.redditmedia.com/r/AskEngineers/comments/1hd7m1k/what_can_i_place_between_my_fish_tank_and_mini/

I hit a wall at showing the vibrations from the fridge were strong enough to cause water changes or that they were any different from the water change supported by the air pump and filters.

I've often wondered that about aquarium air-pumps too. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help], you should then [edit] to add some evidence of your own researches into the topic, your attempt to find an answer and where you hit a wall- we encourage that here.

Note: there is a [pets.se] site on the network that might be of interest to you.

Finding specifics for your model/age of fridge is asking a bit much of humble researchers to have gotten funding to support the study in the first place. For a more complete answer, I seriously doubt anyone's done research that specific. However, bit of judicious poking gave this: Noise and Muscles but that's another mollusk entirely. (Frankly, it's not unreasonable to generalize a little IMHO).
